# How to use border radius in chatjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used doughnut chart in my application, I need border radius but not working, I am using this `borderRadius:30,` could you please solve this issues.

```js
$(function() {

    //get the doughnut chart canvas
    var ctx1 = $("#doughnut-chartcanvas-1");

    //doughnut chart data
    var data1 = {
        labels: ["match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "TeamA Score",
            borderRadius: 30,
            data: [10, 50, 25, 70, 40],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#DEB887",
                "#A9A9A9",
                "#DC143C",
                "#F4A460",
                "#2E8B57"
            ],
            borderColor: [
                "#CDA776",
                "#989898",
                "#CB252B",
                "#E39371",
                "#1D7A46"
            ]
        }]
    };


    //options
    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            text: "Doughnut Chart",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontColor: "#111",

        },
        borderRadius: 100,
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom",
            labels: {
                fontColor: "#333",
                fontSize: 16
            }
        }
    };

    //create Chart class object
    var chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: data1,
        options: options
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ChartJS - Doughnut</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chart-container">
      <div class="doughnut-chart-container">
        <canvas id="doughnut-chartcanvas-1"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ufJC.png)

I need bend each corner in our doughnut chart . So how to use this properties inside of our code (outerStart, outerEnd, innerStart, innerRight). could you please let me know. How do I solve this.

Comment: `borderRadius:30` appears to be changing the radius of each section of the doughnut successfully. Is that not the border radius you're trying to change?

Comment: Hi Rocky, thanks for the replay Yes i need all section border radius how to fix please change my code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The code already changes the border radius of the sections successfully as you can see by running the code snippet above. I'd be happy to help but you'll need to be a lot more explicit about what you want it to do that it isn't already doing.

Comment: When you run the snippet above, notice how each section of the doughnut has rounded corners? That is what `borderRadius` controls. Maybe you're trying to change the size of whole the doughnut? Or the width of the border of each section? Be as precise as possible about what you want it to do differently, please.

Comment: how to use this properties inside of our code (outerStart, outerEnd, innerStart, innerRight) I Have attached images above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var data1 = {
  borderRadius: [{ innerEnd: 200, outerEnd:  200, innerStart: 200, outerStart: 200}],

  spacing: -300,
}
```